# WinRT - How To Get the correct DateTimeFormatter based on the user culture

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, globalization, culture

I've some trouble finding the right DateTimeFormatter for the user.

When converting a date to a string for example with

```
.ToString("D");
```

always the en-US culture is used in WinRT.

I found out that there are new globalization apis which should be used.

for example

```
       var langs = Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages;

       var homeregion = Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.HomeGeographicRegion;


           Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatter(homeregion);
```

but the result of HomeGeographicRegion is not in the format with a new DateTimeformatter requires

I also tried this

```
 var formatter = new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter(Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.YearFormat.Default,
                Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.MonthFormat.Abbreviated,
                Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DayFormat.Default,
                Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DayOfWeekFormat.Default);

                string result = formatter.Format(Date);
```

but that also only returns date string in en-Us format.

Can anyour tell me what is the correct way to get a DateTimeFormatter according to the users culture (which is also automatically used for resource localizations via uid)?

Comment: `ToString(String)` uses the "current" culture.  Are you saying that if you change to something other than en-us, `ToString` still formats as en-us?

Comment: Hmm I dont change it but i expected the culture to be de-DE because ists a german pc without any extra languages. but your right ,the culture is en-us. so why doesnt winrt respect that and sets the culture to it? And so i need to get the user culture in a other way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single argument [DateTimeFormatter constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206834.aspx) takes a template (something like "month.abbreviated day dayofweek"). Providing a region to this will fail with an invalid argument.

For Windows Store applications, the DateTimeFormatters constructed without a languages parameter, will be equivalent to if the DateTimeFormatter had been constructed by providing the value of the [Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.languages.aspx). For desktop applications, the default is the user locale.

Note that the application languages are resolved from the user languages (which you can query at  Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages) and the declared application manifest languages (which you can query at [Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.ManifestLanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.manifestlanguages.aspx)).

Finally, the [ResolvedLanguage property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter.resolvedlanguage.aspx) will let you see exactly what language is being used internally by the DateTimeFormatter.

In my experience, when people get results that they didn't expect, it is generally because the application only supports a single language, in which case, the application language will always be that no matter what the user preference is. Otherwise, verify that the language you expect is at the top of your user language list.

Comment: That was the missing bit. User lang was de-de and en-gb, but in manifest there was only en-us, so the application culture was en-gb which seems logical to me